# loop true and false in javascript

Tags: javascript

Im tryign to loop annything that has triple number will be false otherwise will be true

```
    var noTripple = [1, 1, 2, 2, 1] //return true
var noTripple = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1] // return false
var noTripple = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1] // return false

    

function noTriples(arr) {
  var isTripple = true;
  
  for (var i=3; i + isTripple.length;i++){
    if(arr[i] == 1){
     isTripple++
    }
  }
  
  return isTripple;
}
console.log(noTriples([1,1,2,2,1])); // return true
console.log(noTriples([1,1,2,2,2,1])); // return false
console.log(noTriples([1,1,1,2,2,2,1])); // return false
```

but currently eveything shown on the console is true

Comment: does 'triple' mean 'three in a row'?

Comment: You're not setting either true or false and why are you using `isTripple.length`?

Comment: ` var isTripple = true;` and `isTripple++` So why are you increasing a boolean? Why are you just checking for 1?

Comment: here's a neat one liner `const hasConseq = (count, arr) => arr.slice(0, -(count-1)).reduce((a, b, i) => a || (new Set(arr.slice(i, i+count))).size == 1, false))`

Answer (score 2):

Try checking if there are 3 consecutive same numbers, if yes return false.

Something like this:

```
function noTriples(arr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 2; i++) {
    if (arr[i] == a rr[i + 1] && arr[i + 1] == a rr[i + 2]) {
      return false
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset the counter if the value is not continuing.

```js
const
    noTripple = array => array
        .every(
            (count => (v, i, { [i - 1]: l }) => v === l ? ++count < 3 : (count = 1))
            (0)
        );

console.log(noTripple([1, 1, 2, 2, 1]));       //  true
console.log(noTripple([1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1]));    // false
console.log(noTripple([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1])); // false
```